# Induction Proof of Taylor Series Formula

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, induction, taylor-expansion

I'm attempting to prove a formula for the taylor series of function from a differential equation. 
The equation is
$$f(0)=1$$ $$f'(x) = 2xf(x)$$
I have found empirically that
$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k}}{k!}$$
 **I need to prove that this *general formula* works via induction.**

Here is my attempt!

$$\mathrm{Show} \qquad1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{2}+\frac{x^6}{6}+...+\frac{x^{2k}}{k!}=\sum_{n=0}^k \frac{f^{(2n)}(0)x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

> Prove true for $k=0$

$$1=\frac{f^{(0)}(0)x^{0}}{(0)!}$$
$$1 = 1 \ \checkmark$$

> Assume true for $k=c$

$$1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{2}+...+\frac{x^{2c}}{c!}=\sum_{n=0}^c \frac{f^{(2n)}(0)x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

> Prove true for $k=c+1$

$$\begin{align} 1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{2}+...+\frac{x^{2c}}{c!}+\frac{x^{2c+2}}{(c+1)!}&=\sum_{n=0}^{c+1} \frac{f^{(2n)}(0)x^{2n}}{(2n)!} \\
\sum_{n=0}^c \frac{f^{(2n)}(0)x^{2n}}{(2n)!}+\frac{x^{2c+2}}{(c+1)!}&=\sum_{n=0}^{c+1} \frac{f^{(2n)}(0)x^{2n}}{(2n)!} \\ \frac{x^{2c+2}}{(c+1)!}&=\frac{f^{(2c+2)}(0)x^{2c+2}}{(2c+2)!}
\end{align}$$

From there I don't know how to proceed. Maybe I shouldn't have broken apart the sum on the right? Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I know the differential is easily separable and solvable, but the project involves comparing the solutions

Comment: The truncated series is $not$ a solution so what are you trying to accomplish with the induction? If you want to use series, then propose the solution $f(x)=\sum c_nx^{n}$, determine the constants and then apply existence/uniqueness to your initial value problem.

Comment: I just need to show the general formula works for the series... I don't know what any of that further stuff means

Comment: Try to use induction to come up with an expression for $f^{(n)}(0)$.  The base cases will be given with a little work on the formula $f'(x) = 2x f(x)$  and the chain rule should let you prove the induction hypotheses.  Note that you will have different expressions for even and odd $n$, so two base cases are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: This proof relies on a formula for the $n^{th}$ derivative of $f(x)$ that can be found [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1789074/formula-for-the-nth-derivative-of-a-differential-equation)

The proof is rather extensive, and would roughly quadruple the length of this answer.

Proof  of The Taylor Expansion of $f(x)$
$$\mbox{Prove true that } \ 1 + x^2 + \frac{x^4}{4} + \frac{x^6}{6} + \cdots + \frac{x^{2k}}{k!}=\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{f^{(2n)}(0)x^{(2n)}}{(2n)!}$$

By Induction:

$\circ \text{ Prove true for }k=0$
$$\frac{f^{(0)}(0)x^{0}}{0!} \\ 1=1 \ \checkmark$$

$\circ \text{ Assume true for }k=c$
$$ 1 + x^2 + \frac{x^4}{4} + \frac{x^6}{6} + \cdots + \frac{x^{2c}}{c!}=\sum_{n=0}^{c}\frac{f^{(2n)}(0)x^{(2n)}}{(2n)!}$$

$\circ \text{ Prove true for }k=c+1$

\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
 1 + x^2 + \frac{x^4}{4} + \frac{x^6}{6} + \cdots + \frac{x^{2c}}{c!}+\frac{x^{2c+2}}{(c+1)!}&=\sum_{n=0}^{c+1}\frac{f^{(2n)}(0)x^{(2n)}}{(2n)!} \\ \sum_{n=0}^{c}\frac{f^{(2n)}(0)x^{(2n)}}{(2n)!}+\frac{x^{2c+2}}{(c+1)!}&=\sum_{n=0}^{c+1}\frac{f^{(2n)}(0)x^{(2n)}}{(2n)!}  \mbox{By I.H}
 \\ =\sum_{n=0}^{c}\frac{f^{(2n)}(0)x^{(2n)}}{(2n)!}+\frac{x^{2c+2}}{(c+1)!} \cdot \frac{(2c+2)!}{(2c+2)!}
 \\=\sum_{n=0}^{c}\frac{f^{(2n)}(0)x^{(2n)}}{(2n)!}+\frac{x^{2c+2}}{(2c+2)!} \cdot \frac{(2c+2)!}{(c+1)!}
 \\=\sum_{n=0}^{c}\frac{f^{(2n)}(0)x^{(2n)}}{(2n)!}+\frac{x^{2c+2}}{(2c+2)!} \cdot \frac{(2c+2)!}{(\frac{2c+2}{2})!}
 \\=\sum_{n=0}^{c}\frac{f^{(2n)}(0)x^{(2n)}}{(2n)!}+\frac{x^{2c+2}}{(2c+2)!} \cdot f^{(2c+2)}(0) \mbox{ From linked proof}
 \\=\sum_{n=0}^{c+1}\frac{f^{(2n)}(0)x^{(2n)}}{(2n)!} \checkmark
\end{split}
\end{equation}

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k}}{k!} \mathrm{Q.E.D}$$

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your formula,
the proof is straightforward.

If
$f(x) 
= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k}}{k!}
$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
f'(x) 
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2kx^{2k-1}}{k!}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2kx^{2k-1}}{k!}
\qquad\text{since the }k=0\text{ term is zero}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2x^{2k-1}}{(k-1)!}
\qquad\text{cancelling }k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2x^{2k+1}}{k!}
\qquad\text{shifting }k\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2xx^{2k}}{k!}\\
&= 2x\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k}}{k!}\\
&=2xf(x)\\
\end{array}
$,