# Formula for the nth Derivative of a Differential Equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have the differential equation
$$f'(x)=2xf(x)$$
With the initial condition that $f(0)=1$

I need to prove that the nth derivative evaluated at zero is equivalent to $n!/(n/2)!$ for even n.
$$\text{Show  } f^{(n)}(0)=\frac{n!}{(n/2)!} \text{ for even values of n}$$

I have tried using the general Leibniz rule, which gives me that

$$\left[ \sum_{k=0}^c \frac{c!}{k!(c-k)!}(2x)^{(k)}(f^{(c-k)}(x)) \right]_{x=0}=\frac{c!}{(c/2)!}$$
 But then I don't know how to proceed from here, any guidance would be appreciated!

Note: I know the solution is $e^{x^2}$ but the problem involves comparing the series expansion and differntial equation, so I need to be able to solve this part.

Comment: You can _solve_ your IVP explicitly, then use the known power series for the solution....

Comment: Yes, it's clearly $e^{x^2}$, but the problem involves comparing the derived power series and the solution from the differential equation.

Comment: You can write the solution as a power series in two ways:$$e^{x^{2}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2k}}{k!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!} x^{n}.$$Comparing coefficients does the job. :)

Comment: In this portion of the assignment, I cannot use any "known" series, I have to do it from the derivatives. I have found both of those equations, and this whole thing is about proving their equivalency. If I could prove the above, I would be able to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k$. Then 
\begin{equation}
f'(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k a_k x^{k-1} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k a_k x^{k-1} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty (m+1) a_{m+1} x^m, \tag{1}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
 2 x f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2a_k x^{k+1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2 a_{n-1} x^n.\tag{2}
\end{equation}
Equating $(1)$ and $(2)$ term by term, you obtain a recurrence relation for the coefficients $a_n$. The initial condition $f(0) = 1$ yields $a_0 = 1$. You can now use the recursive relation to prove the statement.

Comment: How can you equate them term by term, when you don't know anything about that equivalency. I can find the equation $2a_2 x + 3a_3 x^2 + 4a_4 x^3 +...+ = 2a_0 x + 2a_1 x^2 + 2 a_2 x^3 +...+$ but I don't see how that's helpful. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Moving everything to one side of the equation, so to speak, you get $\sum_k [...] x^k = 0$. This is an identity for all $x$, i.e. the function on the left hand side, as described by the series, must be equal to the zero function on the right hand side. The zero function has a unique series expansion, given by $0 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty 0\cdot x^k$. If two functions are equal, their series expansions are equal. Therefore, you obtain that $(k+1)a_{k+1} - 2 a_{k-1} = 0$ for every $k \geq 0$.

Comment: Okay. I follow you through that, but how does this allow me to prove that $f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{n!}{(n/2)!}$? It appears this just leads me back to my initial given.

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you can use the recurrence relation to try to find an expression for $a_k$ in terms of $k$.

Comment: I'm almost through it, but I have a problem with your indexing. If orginially you said that $m=k-1$ and $n=k+1$ you dont get $(k+1)a_{k+1} - 2 a_{k-1} = 0$, you get $(k+1)a_{k+1} - 2 a_{k} = 0$

Comment: The indexing is correct. I introduced $m=k-1$ and $n=k+1$ to obtain a 'simple' power of $x$, i.e. one of the form $x^a$, in order to be able to compare the two series. In the series for $f'(x)$, the index had to be increased by one, yielding $k a_k \to (m+1) a_{m+1}$. In the series for $2 x f(x)$, the index had to be decreased by one, yielding $a_k \to a_{n-1}$. Now, the two resulting series both have the form $\sum a_p x^p$, so you can compare them term by term.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help by user [Frits Veerman](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/273748/frits-veerman), I have completed the problem!

To show the derivatives at zero are as states, I will show that the coefficients of the Taylor series are:
$$ a_k=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{(k/2)!},  & \text{if $k$ is even} \\
0, & \text{if $k$ is odd}
\end{cases}$$
Show the coefficients of the Taylor series for $f(x)$ are $\frac{1}{(n/2)!}$ (for even n):
$$f(x) \text{ is analytic, as it is infinitely differentiable everywhere.}$$
$$\text{Let } f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k$$
$$\text{Show } a_k = \frac{1}{(k/2)!} \mbox{ For even k}$$
From the initial conditions:
$$f(x) = 1 + 0 + x^2 + ... + = a_0x^0 + a_1x^1 + a_2x^2 + ... +$$
By direct comparison, the initial conditions for the series $\sum a_k x^k$ are $a_0 = 1$ and $a_1 = 0$

\begin{split}
    f'(x) &=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}ka_kx^{k-1}
    \\ &\mbox{Let $m=k-1$}
    \\ &=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(m+1)a_{m+1}x^{m}
    \\\mbox {And } 2xf(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 2a_kx^{k+1}
    \\&\mbox{Let $n=k+1$}
    \\ &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2a_{n-1}x^n
    \\ f'(x) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(m+1)a_{m+1}x^{m} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2a_{n-1}x^n
    \\ a_1 + 2a_2x + 3a_3x^2+\cdots+(m+1)a_{m+1}x^m &= +2a_0x + 2a_1x^2
    \\&+2a_2x^3+\cdots+2a_{n-1}x^n
    \\ \mbox{(Note $a_1=0$)}
    \\ \mbox{This relationship holds for all $x$, so we will evaluate at $x = 1$.}
    \\ \mbox{Return to k index for direct comparison.}
    \\ a_1 + 2a_2+3a_3+4a_4+\cdots+&=2a_0+2a_1+2a_2+2a_3+\cdots+
    \\ (2a_2-2a_0) + (3a_3-2a_1)+(4a_4-2a_2)+\cdots+((k+1)a_{k+1}-2a_{k-1}) &= 0 = \sum 0
\end{split}

By the properties of the zero series, each term of the equivalent series must also be zero. Most notably,
$(k+1)a_{k+1}-2a_{k-1}=0$
Simple manipulation gives the recursive formula:
$$a_k = \frac{2a_{k-2}}{k}$$
From initial conditions and recursive formula:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    a_0 &= 1
    \\a_1 &=0
    \\a_2 &= 1
    \\a_3 &=0
    \\a_4 &= \frac{1}{2}
    \\a_5 &=0
    \\a_6 &= \frac{1}{6}
    \\a_7 &= 0
    \\a_8 &= \frac{1}{24}
    \\&  \vdots
\end{split}
\end{equation}
This appears to take the form $a_k = \frac{1}{(k/2)!}$ for even $k$, $a_k=0$ for odd $k$, Which we now prove:
Case 1 - k is even:
$$\text{Show } a_k =\frac{2a_{k-2}}{k} = \frac{1}{(k/2)!} \text{ For even k, Given $a_0=1$} $$
By induction:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split} 
     \mbox{ $\circ$ Show true for $k=2$} \qquad \qquad  \qquad \qquad&
    \\ a_2 &= \frac{2 \cdot 1}{2} = \frac{1}{(2/2)!} = 1 \checkmark
    \\ \mbox{ $\circ$ Assume true for $k=c$} \quad \qquad  \qquad \qquad&
    \\a_c &= \frac{2a_{c-2}}{c} = \frac{1}{(c/2)!}
    \\ \mbox{ $\circ$ Prove true for $k=c+2$ } \  \qquad  \qquad \qquad&
    \\a_{c+2} &= \frac{2a_c}{c+2} = \frac{1}{(\frac{c+2}{2})!}
    \\&=\frac{\frac{2}{(c/2)!}}{c+2} \qquad \qquad \mbox{By I.H}
    \\&=\frac{2}{(c+2)(c/2)!} \cdot \frac{1/2}{1/2}
    \\&=\frac{1}{(\frac{c+2}{2})(c/2)!}
    \\&=\frac{1}{(\frac{c}{2}+1)(c/2)!}
    \\&=\frac{1}{(\frac{c}{2}+1)!}
    \\&=\frac{1}{(\frac{c+2}{2})!}
    \\ &\mbox{Q.E.D}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Case 2 - k is odd
$\circ$ Show $a_k =\frac{2a_{k-2}}{k} = 0$  For odd k, Given $a_1=0$
By Induction:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split} 
    \\ \mbox{ $\circ$ Show true for $k=3$} \qquad \qquad  \qquad \qquad&
    \\ a_3 &= \frac{2 \cdot 0}{3} = 0 \checkmark
    \\  \mbox{ $\circ$ Assume true for $k=c$} \quad \qquad  \qquad \qquad&
    \\a_c &= \frac{2a_{c-2}}{c} = 0
    \\  \mbox{ $\circ$ Prove true for $k=c+2$ } \  \qquad  \qquad \qquad&
    \\a_{c+2} &= \frac{2a_c}{c+2} 
    \\&= \frac{2 \cdot 0}{c+2} \qquad \qquad \mbox{By I.H}
    \\&=0
    \\ &\mbox{Q.E.D}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
$\therefore$ The coefficients of the Taylor Series have been shown:
$$ a_k=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{(k/2)!},  & \text{if $k$ is even} \\
0, & \text{if $k$ is odd}
\end{cases}$$